# Current Location not Getting when Android background Service Start Using Alarm Manager

Tags: android, google-maps, location, alarmmanager

I want to Current location and sent that location on my ASP.Net Web service.
I write following code.
Background Service is start by using this code but i don`t get Location. 
OnLocationChange() Method is not called.
Please Help me.

Following Code:

Set Alarm Code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static boolean AlarmSet(Context context, String function, AlarmManager alarmMan) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = alarmMan;
    PendingIntent pending_intent;
    DatabaseHandler DB;
    try {
        DB = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        String state = function;
        final Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (state.contains("setall")) {
            String result = DB.ConvStrSelctTripTimeDetails();

            String[] row = result.split("##@@");
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

                String[] data = row[i].split("#");

                int rowid = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);

                int shiftid = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);

                int dayid = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
                if (dayid != 7) {
                    dayid = dayid + 1;
                } else {
                    dayid = 1;
                }

                String[] strtIN = data[3].split(":");
                String[] endIN = data[4].split(":");
                String[] strtOUT = data[5].split(":");
                String[] endOUT = data[6].split(":");

                String alarmStartIN = "1";

                //IN_Start
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strtIN[0]));
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strtIN[1]));
                calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayid);
                myIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", String.valueOf(shiftid));
                myIntent.putExtra("ops", "s");
                alarmStartIN = String.valueOf(rowid) + "1";
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarmStartIN), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
                common.writelog("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);
                Log.e("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);

                //IN_End
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(endIN[0]));
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(endIN[1]));
                calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayid);
                myIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", String.valueOf(shiftid));
                myIntent.putExtra("ops", "e");
                alarmStartIN = String.valueOf(rowid) + "2";
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarmStartIN), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
                common.writelog("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);
                Log.e("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);

                //OUT_Start
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(strtOUT[0]));
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(strtOUT[1]));
                calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayid);
                myIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", String.valueOf(shiftid));
                myIntent.putExtra("ops", "s");
                alarmStartIN = String.valueOf(rowid) + "3";
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarmStartIN), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
                common.writelog("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);
                Log.e("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);

                //OUT_End
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(endOUT[0]));
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(endOUT[1]));
                calendar.set(calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayid);
                myIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", String.valueOf(shiftid));
                myIntent.putExtra("ops", "e");
                alarmStartIN = String.valueOf(rowid) + "4";
                pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarmStartIN), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
                common.writelog("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);
                Log.e("common", "AlarmSet() Alram Set ID :" + alarmStartIN);
            }


        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        common.writelog("common", "AlarmSet() Value:"+ function +": Error:361:" + ex.getMessage());
        Log.e("common", "onCreate() Value:"+ function +": Error:361:" + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver File Code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 180000;
public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 180000;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String ShiftID = intent.getExtras().getString("ShiftID");
    Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() ShiftID : " + ShiftID);
    common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() ShiftID : " + ShiftID);

    if(context==null)
    {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver","Context:null");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver","Context:Not null");
    }
    String ops = intent.getExtras().getString("ops");
    Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() ops : " + ops);
    common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() ops : " + ops);

    if (ops.equals("s")) {
        try {
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            boolean statusOfGPS = manager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    /*
                     * if (!statusOfGPS) { showGPSDisabledAlertToUser(); }
                     */
            // startAt10();
            // start();
            common.Running = true;
            buildGoogleApiClient(context);
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() Error: 48 : " + ex.getMessage());
            common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() ShiftID : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() Start Service : " + ShiftID);
        common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() Start Service : " + ShiftID);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", ShiftID);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ops", ops);
        assert context != null;
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

        //context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));

    } else if (ops.equals("e")) {

        Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() End Service : " + ShiftID);
        common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "onReceive() End Service : " + ShiftID);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ShiftID", ShiftID);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("ops", ops);
        assert context != null;
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(Context contex) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(contex)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    createLocationRequest();
}

private void createLocationRequest() {
    try {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        common.writelog("AlarmReceiver", "createLocationRequest()86: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

MyService Code:

```
    package com.expedite.apps.vehiclelocation;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.provider.Settings;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
    import android.text.format.Time;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BOOMBOOMTESTGPS";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 2f;
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION_VISITED = "http://tempuri.org/setVechicleLocation";
    private static String METHOD_SEND_LOCATION_DATA = "setVechicleLocation";
    private static String URL = "http://vts.vayuna.com/Service.asmx";
    public String buskey = "";
    boolean isget = false;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        Location mLastLocation;

        public LocationListener(String provider) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
                common.writelog(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
                mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LocationListener() Error:48 " + ex.getMessage());
                common.writelog(TAG, "LocationListener() Error:48 " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            try {
                mLastLocation.set(location);
                Time time = new Time();
                time.setToNow();
                if (common.lat != location.getLatitude() || common.lon != location.getLongitude() || common.minut != time.minute) {
                    common.lat = location.getLatitude();
                    common.lon = location.getLongitude();
                    common.accu = location.getAccuracy();
                    common.minut = time.minute;
                    common.time = time.hour + ":" + time.minute + ":" + time.second;
                    new MyTask().execute();
                    common.writelog(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.getAccuracy());
                } else {
                }
                // Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
            common.writelog(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
            common.writelog(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
            common.writelog(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }
    }

   /* LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };*/

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    };

    public MyService() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            common.writelog(TAG, "onStartCommand");
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return START_STICKY;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand() Error:120 " + ex.getMessage());
            common.writelog(TAG, "onStartCommand() Error:120 " + ex.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        common.writelog(TAG, "onCreate");
        DatabaseHandler DB = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        String Res = DB.ConvStrBusMaster();
        if (!Res.equals("")) {
            try {
                String[] respons = Res.split("#@#@");
                buskey = respons[3].toString();
                Log.e("MyService", "onCreate() buskey"+buskey);
                common.writelog("MyService", "onCreate() buskey"+buskey);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                common.writelog("MyService::onCreate()", "Error: 121 MSG:" + ex.getMessage());
                Log.e("MyService", "onCreate() Error: 121 MSG:" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
       /* Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        common.writelog(TAG, "onCreate");
        if (isget == false) {
            buskey =common.busid;
            isget = true;
        }*/
        initializeLocationManager();
       /* try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[1]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            common.writelog(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore::: "+ ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
            common.writelog(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }*/
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
            common.writelog(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore::: "+ ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
            common.writelog(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        try {


            Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
            if (mLocationManager == null) {
                mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            }
        }catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "initializeLocationManager() Error:202 " + ex.getMessage());
            common.writelog(TAG, "initializeLocationManager() Error:202 " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SendDataToServer();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public void SendDataToServer() {
        // $,GJ05AV4839,4503791073,140416111538,21.172227,72.849145,0,0,0,0,#
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                METHOD_SEND_LOCATION_DATA);
        Time time = new Time();
        String LocationDetails = "";
        try {
            if (common.lat != 0.0 && common.lon != 0.0) {
                time.setToNow();
                String m_androidId = "Service "
                        + Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy:HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                /*LocationDetails = "$,XPD55," + time.hour + ":" + time.minute
                        + ":" + time.second + "," + common.time + " Accuracy:"
                        + common.accu + "," + common.lat + "," + common.lon
                        + ",0,0,0," + m_androidId + ",#";*/


                LocationDetails="$," + buskey + "," + buskey + "," + currentTimeStamp + "," + common.lat + ","
                        + common.lon + ",0,0,Accuracy:" + common.accu + ",0,#";

                common.writelog("Service", "SendLocation() 311:"+ common.lat+","+ common.lon+","+common.accu+", Details::"+LocationDetails+" , Url:"+URL);
                request.addProperty("vehicleinfo", LocationDetails);
                request.addProperty("device", buskey);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,
                        100000);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_VISITED, envelope);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                common.writelog("MyService","SendDataToServer()"+LocationDetails);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            common.writelog("Service", "Exception 288:" + ex.getMessage()
                    + ":::/n" + ex.getStackTrace());
        }
    }

}
```